# Debug VMWare Process with Visual Studio: Login Failed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, vmware, remote-debugging, vmware-workstation

From a Windows7 host, I have a process running under a Windows10 VM from VMWare.  Using Visual Studio 2013 and the VMWare remote debugging plugin, I want to attach to this process.  When I try, I'm prompted for my Username and Password but after entering such, I get the error:

> Login Failed.  Authentication failure or insufficient permissions in
>   guest operating system.

The "Attach to Process" dialog has the correct "Running Virtual Machine" and associated "Virtual Machine Location".  The "Remote Debug Monitor" is set to the path on the *host* of `...\Remote Debugger\x86\msvsmon.exe`.  The "Remote Debug Monitor Name" is set to "VMDebug".

My Win7 host is part of a domain but the Win10 guest is not.  They have different passwords.  I *am* able to do remote-debugging on a Win7 VM that is also on the domain.  There I connect as "COMPANY\bcwhite" with my password that is the same as the host.

The first obvious question is: *What is the correct "User name" because Win10 doesn't make this obvious?*  Is it "Brian White", "bcwhite", or "bcwhite@example.com"?  Granted, I've tried all three and always get the same error.

The second question is: *What other permissions could the guest operating system need?*  How do I get more information?

Comment: It used to be the best to take the exact same user on both machines for debugging. Can you make the Win10 machine part of the domain and then log in with your domain user?

Comment: Do you have the [debug privilege](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291232%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on Win10?

Comment: Did you "run as administrator"? Otherwise it could happen that privileges cannot be inherited correctly.

Comment: @Thomas, I can't join the Win10 VM to the domain.  The user is the only one and does have administrator privileges. At least, that's what it says under "Your account" and I can install apps system-wide.  Took a bit to locate "Debug Programs" under Win10... It is set to "Administrators".  I explicitly added my own account to it anyway and restarted the VM -- no change.